# Transforming a column index in Python pandas

Tags: python, pandas, indexing

I have the following DataFrame:

```
   index    PUBLICO     CLASSIFICACAO_PUBLICO
0   19      143643          1
1   34      111879          2
2   31       50382          3
3   9        49204          4
4   32       37541          5
5   4        36095          6
```

I need convert the index name column to index column.

For example:

```
index   PUBLICO     CLASSIFICACAO_PUBLICO
19      143643          1
34      111879          2
31       50382          3
9        49204          4
32       37541          5
4        36095          6
```

I try use `df.set_index('index')`, but it didn't work.

The column with the name `index` previously was the index column the DataFrame, but I used `reset_index()`; now I need to do the reverse.

Comment: what's your expected output? `df1 = df.set_index('index'); df1.index.name=None` works fine on my side.

Comment: What do you mean by "it didn't work"? Did you get an error message? An unexpected result? Please edit your question to add that information.

Comment: did you pass param `inplace=True`? `set_index` returns a copy of the df with the index set to your column

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The method `set_index` doesn't work inplace. So that you have to reassign your dataframe, or to pass the option `inplace = True`:

```
df = df.set_index('index')
```

or

```
df.set_index('index',inplace = True)
```

see http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html

Answer (score 0):

You can try it this way:

```
df.set_index(df['index'], inplace=True)
```

This will set your `index` column as the index in your dataframe and your `index` column will still remain in your dataframe as well. Then, you can just drop that column.

```
df.drop('index', axis=1, inplace=True)
```